# Actionscript 2 Disable a button after a scene

Tags: flash, button, actionscript-2, scene

I'm just a newbie in ActionScript and we are required to make a game using ActionScript 2.

So, I have this main scene with three buttons, when I press one of the buttons, it will go to a mini game. When the player succeeds in the mini game, it will go back to the main scene and the button that is pressed is disabled. Right now, what I can only do is when it is pressed the button is disabled, it does not go to the scene for the mini game. Can anyone help me?

here's the code :

```
stop();

var places:Array = [flood_btn, earthquake_btn, landslide_btn];
var pressedbtn;

function Dplaces():Void {

    pressedbtn.enabled = true;
    this.enabled = false;

}

for (ctr = 0; ctr < places.length; ctr++) {
    places[ctr].onRelease = Dplaces;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I didn't see how do you go to the other scenes from the main one and of course you have to understand that every time you go back to the main scene every thing will be initialized, so you have to treat that using, for example, a global var like this :

```
stop();

// verify if this is our first run, so create our global pressed_btn var
// otherwise, pressed_btn contains the current pressed button index
if (pressed_btn == undefined)
{
    _global.pressed_btn = -1;

}

var places:Array = [flood_btn, earthquake_btn, landslide_btn];

// init our buttons and disable, if we have, the current pressed one
for (ctr = 0; ctr < places.length; ctr++)
{   
    var btn:Button = places[ctr];
    if (ctr != pressed_btn)
    {   
        // we add the index attribut to identify our button when it's pressed to go to the appropriate scene
        btn['index'] = ctr;     
        btn.onRelease = Dplaces;
    } else {
        // if we have a pressed button, disable it
        btn.enabled = false;
    }
}

function Dplaces():Void {

    // save the current pressed button index
    _global.pressed_btn = this.index;

    switch (this.index)
    {
        case 0 :
            gotoAndStop("game1", 1);
            break;
        case 1 :
            gotoAndStop("game2", 1);
            break;
        case 2 :
            gotoAndStop("game3", 1);
            break;
    }

}
```

Hope that can help.